# Extending Wordpress as a full-scale CMS

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

I know that most people will consider this post as irrelevant, and yes, I've read tens of posts saying that Wordpress is "just a blogging platform". However, facts speak for themselves - people do use Wordpress a lot. Moreover, large projects are being developed using Wordpress as the underlying platform. Who doesn't believe it could check the showcase. Even my team has developed a couple of magazine websites full of rich media and different content types.

The point is: what can we do to make the development, and management process even easier? I hope that this post will draw the attention of Pro wordpress users and a lot of plugins, extensions, and techniques will be posted here. Please, do not hesitate to share your experience, if you have done a project with WP that is way out of its "blogging only" capabilities.

Thanks.

Comment: um... wouldn't you get more feedback from a wordpress forum on this? I also know that WPMU has many forums / blogs with ideas around this.

Comment: So what is your main purpose? To collect a list of plugins or a list of extraordinary WP projects? You can guess what you get, I think the result of this question isn't very surprising. 

All the Wordpress projects, even the projects that go way beyond blogging will have one thing in common: they show news to people. Why should you use Wordpress without populating the posts table in the Wordpress database?

Comment: I'd guess that's way more than enough for many companies. Still, the main purpose of CMS platforms is displaying lots of heterogeneous info, be it posts, news, and even products

Answer (score 1):

You're right, Wordpress can be extended to do anything. After all it's just a database with functions that put stuff in and take stuff out. Speaking from experience, I found that the API is pretty robust and can accomplish anything you want to, however, it's probably better to spec something out and build it yourself using a more agile framework like RoR.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes less is more. 
It is amazing how much one could achieve using simple concepts such as posts, pages, categories, tags, and custom fields. The thing that I do not like in many content management frameworks and more advanced CMSes is that they often hinder development by putting too much abstraction on top of simple concepts like these. With Wordpress I could prototype a site in less than a day, again due to simple templating options which, of course can be extended on demand.

No one says that code should be written here and there with no structure at all. The thing is that WP API allows enough options to add abstractions when and where needed.

I remain a clear proponent of the use of WP for bigger projects than originally intended. All that is necessary is a little twist of mentality.

Of course, WP is not without its drawbacks. Its strongest side, the plugin community could turn out to be its weakest one, unless measures are taken to educate newbie plugin developers about some good practices. I've worked with some great plugins that fail in users's eyes because of weak API and integration hardships. Nobody would care about functionality if they cannot integrate the plugin at all, right ?

Anyone sharing any of this?

Answer (score 0):

Two pretty good plpugins for extending wordpress beyond blogging are flutter and pods that allow you to do more with custom fields, in pods case much more.